# Can't Delete Records In Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models. Customer, Job, and Receipt.

Customer has many Jobs and Jobs has many Receipts. Job belongs to Customer and Receipts belongs to Job.

In my delete def for my customer, I want to delete all of the customers jobs and the job receipts. Here is my controller code

```
def destroy
    customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    customer.jobs.receipts.destroy_all #this line crashes
    customer.jobs.destroy_all
    customer.destroy
    redirect_to customers_url

    redirect_to show_todays_jobs_path
end
```

The line that says customer.jobs.receipts.destroy_all throws an error that states that the receipts method is undefined.

However, in my Jobs controller, jobs.receipts.destroy_all works just fine. In the customer controller if I remove the line to destroy receipts then that works fine too.

I don't understand why it I can't delete the receipts in the Customer controller. Please help me out here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show Jobs controller?

Comment: We need to see the model relations you have.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your code that `customer.jobs` is a collection where *each* job record has its own collection of receipts. You may use association `has_many :receipts, through: :jobs` in the Customer model to obtain direct `customer.receipts` reference, then you can call `customer.receipts.delete_all`. [Documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Seems you could use `dependent: :destroy` or `dependent: :delete_all` for your associations `has_many`, briefly it will delete associations when the `customer` object is destroyed. Checkout the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#dependent).

Take a look on code example:

```
class Customer
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
end


class Job
  has_many :receipts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Then when you call `customer.destroy` all related jobs and receipts could be destroyed as well.

PS. You have another mistake in controller code - `redirect_to` called twice, only one time is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing these deletes yourself manually in your controller. There are parameters you can provide to your associations in your models to tell them to destroy the associated records when destroying the parent.

I've made some assumptions about your model associations, but something along the lines of the following should work for you:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :receipts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Setting `dependent: :destroy` on the association tells rails to delete the associated records by calling their `destroy` method when deleting the parent object.

With this set up, you can just do this in your `destroy` action within your controller (note there's no need to `find` your record before you `destroy` it):

```
def destroy
  Customer.destroy(params[:id])
  redirect_to customers_url
end
```